# Where can I find a unix command line parameters standardized documentation?

Tags: php, unix, standards

I am writing a custom command-line application in php and I want to use the default UNIX parsing style for the parameters.

By default, I get the $argv array, which is a representation of all parameters formatted in a line.

Is there somewhere a document which describes how parameters should be interpreted in a UNIX program? For example, am I allowed to attach values using parameter with only one "-"? ("-i=25")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base Specifications, Issue 7 or IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 edition is what you are looking for.

Here is a link to the section relating to arguments for command line utilities.

[12.1 Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)